# My boss moved me to a new role. Am I legally entitled to a title/salary review?

Tags: salary, title

I'm an engineer but I know a lot of programming and software. I have an engineering title and used to work under an engineering manager. About 4 months ago, my manager's manager came to me and told me he was "temporarily" moving me to a role as a software developer on a project. I now report to my manager's manager and don't do anything related to my previous engineering role.

The org chart, my salary, and my job title/description have not changed. However, it has recently become clear after the latest large software release I worked on that this change is no longer temporary and is permanent.

I work for a Fortune 500 company. The median salary for what I'm currently doing is significantly more than what I used to be doing. Plus I feel that the flexibility and value I provide as an employee isn't reflected in what I'm being paid. Am I entitled to a review of my job title/description, compensation, etc.? If I am, should I talk with my manager if I suspect he is trying to take advantage of me? Or should I talk to an ombudsman or HR?

### Some Clarification:

I knew exactly what I would be doing in this "temporary" role when I was assigned. This is not a question about what to do when the job is not what I thought it would be.

While I do feel I am being underpaid, this is about whether or not I am entitled to a review. Not even a raise, just a review. Like, does the company legally have to make the org chart/job title/description reflect reality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: Entitled to one? Very likely not, but you should certainly *request* one.

Comment: Legal questions are out of scope. However, it is my experience in the workplace that requests are far more likely to have positive outcomes than threats of legal action. YMMV.

Comment: Yes you should march into your bosses office and demand one immediately!

Comment: The answer to the specific question is there is no *legal* aspect involved, at all. unfortunately, the pressure is *entirely on you* to demand more money: you should do it, using the good advice below.

Comment: @HLGEM I'm not looking to take legal action. I just want to know for when I talk to my boss. So that if he doesn't want to renegotiate my position/pay, I can inform him of the legal side.

Comment: I would suggest reviewing your HR handbook. It may contain a description of how you can ask for an evaluation of your position title and pay scale based on duties assigned. Many large companies have a specific HR process for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 5):

An old saying, "Every day you come to work interviewing for your job.  Every payday they try to convince you to keep it."

It certainly sounds like it's time to have a meeting about your job assignment and role.

Don't just go in saying, "I need more."  Have your market research, and if possible, job titles and descriptions within your company that match your current duties.

Lay it out as a matter-of-fact case.  Don't put any emotion into it, and certainly don't say you're "entitled."  Present it as, "This is what the role should be, what it should pay, and I've certainly demonstrated that I am qualified for the role."

You can't force them to do anything, but neither do they have you chained to your desk.

Answer (score 1):

You have no *legal* entitlement unless you work for a government agency where policy is all written down in a rule-book and followed to the letter.  But since you work for a Fortune 500, all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

> Like, does the company legally have to make the org chart/job title/description reflect reality?

It all depends on your contract - if your employment agreement has not been modified, then they have no obligation. But of course, it may be in their interest (and yours) to discuss the matter if the change is going to be permanent (or else, you could just walk away e.g. if you feel underpaid).